# Overriding Devise Registrations#create without copy/paste the logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, devise

So, I have my own registrations controller in my app, which adds a role assignment for a newly registered user

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource
    resource.role = Role.find_by_name('registered')
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any cleaner way to add functionality to this method? I'd prefer not to have to have devise's code copy/pasted into my method to keep their logic separated from mine.

I suppose I can handle it at the model level, with a callback, but I'm not sure what the best practice

Comment: Skinny controller, fat model.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just refactoring this to a callback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_role

  private
  def set_role
    if self.role.nil?
      self.role = Role.find_by_name('registered')
    end
  end
end
```

Much cleaner. Got rid of the customer devise controller altogether.